# Gradle is unable to download com.netflix.graphql.dgs:*.jar?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build.gradle, netflix-dgs

Gradle is unable to download `com.netflix.graphql.dgs:*.jar` artifacts even though these artifacts exists in the [maven central repo](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/netflix/graphql/dgs/).

```
C:\Users\abc\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.netflix.graphql.dgs\graphql-dgs-client>dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 6666-0C00

 Directory of C:\Users\abc\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.netflix.graphql.dgs\graphql-dgs-client

07/25/2023  01:27 AM    <DIR>          .
07/25/2023  01:27 AM    <DIR>          ..
07/24/2023  11:55 PM    <DIR>          4.9.15
07/24/2023  11:16 PM    <DIR>          6.0.0
07/25/2023  12:52 AM    <DIR>          6.0.1
07/25/2023  01:27 AM    <DIR>          7.0.0
07/24/2023  11:40 PM    <DIR>          7.3.0
07/24/2023  11:13 PM    <DIR>          7.3.2
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               8 Dir(s)  23,834,460,160 bytes free
```

Its creating the directory structure. But the directories don't have *.jar or source jars. **For example -**

```
C:\Users\abc\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.netflix.graphql.dgs\graphql-dgs-client\7.0.0>dir /s
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 6666-0C00

 Directory of C:\Users\abc\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.netflix.graphql.dgs\graphql-dgs-client\7.0.0

07/25/2023  01:27 AM    <DIR>          .
07/25/2023  01:27 AM    <DIR>          ..
07/25/2023  01:27 AM    <DIR>          5c56063934776448d4bf3c263329e17a3d16fcca
07/25/2023  01:27 AM    <DIR>          6bcd39f7d317f7cf7995c7581d5309d87da6e656
               0 File(s)              0 bytes

 Directory of C:\Users\abc\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.netflix.graphql.dgs\graphql-dgs-client\7.0.0\5c56063934776448d4bf3c263329e17a3d16fcca

07/25/2023  01:27 AM    <DIR>          .
07/25/2023  01:27 AM    <DIR>          ..
07/25/2023  01:27 AM             5,625 graphql-dgs-client-7.0.0.pom
               1 File(s)          5,625 bytes

 Directory of C:\Users\abc\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.netflix.graphql.dgs\graphql-dgs-client\7.0.0\6bcd39f7d317f7cf7995c7581d5309d87da6e656

07/25/2023  01:27 AM    <DIR>          .
07/25/2023  01:27 AM    <DIR>          ..
07/25/2023  01:27 AM             7,251 graphql-dgs-client-7.0.0.module
               1 File(s)          7,251 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
               2 File(s)         12,876 bytes
               8 Dir(s)  23,834,071,040 bytes free
```

And in intellij i get below error message -

```
myprj:test: Could not resolve com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-client:6.0.2.
Required by:
    project :

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

My Environment is -
-windows 10
-gradlew - 8.1.1
-java 11

Note: Download of other artifacts like `apache httpclient` or `mysql-connector-j` etc is happening as expected without any issues.

**Edit -** as suggested build.gradle is as below -

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.2.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.abc'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    implementation group: 'com.netflix.graphql.dgs', name: 'graphql-dgs-client', version: '6.0.2'
    implementation 'com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-extended-scalars:7.2.0'
    implementation 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:8.1.0'

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Needs more detail, as a dependency of `implementation 'com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-client:6.0.2'` downloads just fine

Comment: @CodeBot you should provide the gradle script to understand what repositories and dependencies it declares. That is kind of basic information to provide to troubleshoot a gradle build issue.

Comment: @aled - added build.gradle to Q. Thx for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe because you don't have the **starter dependency**.

Add this to your build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-spring-boot-starter'
```